# row[0].value or msql query fault?

Tags: javascript, mysql

When i start my steam bot im getting an error which looks like this:

http://gyazo.com/8f977b440ad8d75f5e0be698bf89b91e

I'm wondering though, how would i know which code is the problem?

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`=\`maxitems\`'
```

It may not be finding the maxitems so it is saying row[0].value doesn't make sense?

I know that maxitems is there because when i search the query

```
'SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`= 'maxitems'
```

on the mysql database it can find it.

Or

```
 row[0].value
```

It doesn't know that im wanting the value that is on the row?

Answer (score 0):

Use \' as value of name column instead of `. ', " represent String ` database structure elements like table name or column etc.

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`=\'maxitems\'');
```

OR

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`="maxitems"');
```